# Posts List not displaying in Wordpress admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress

I Have 260 posts in Wordpress blog. But only the first one is displaying in the admin panel. (wp-admin/edit.php). Pages and comments list are loading without any issues.

[image: Only One post is displayed here]

The server error log says:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in /home/jxjx/public_html/jxjxjx.com/wp-includes/class-wp-list-util.php on line 152, referer: https://jxjxjx.com/wp-admin/edit.php

Tried these:

- Updating Wordpress, Themes and Plugins.
- Disabling All plugins.
- Reinstalling Wordpress.
- Cleaning up and Optimizing the database.
- Allocating More memory and execution time. 
  Update
- Changing the theme to default

But on the front end, everything works well. What can be the problem ?

Comment: On the "wp-admin/edit.php" double check that the "Number of items per page:" in "Screen Options" on the upper right hand is set to more then 1.

Comment: Did this happen when migrating to a new server?

Comment: Yes, Its more than 1 in screen options.

Comment: No. It is not a migrated Wordpress Installation.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a theme issue. You said you disabled all plugins, which is great, but what happens if you revert to the default 2017 theme?

Also, edit `wp-config.php` (located in the main install folder), and near the bottom, set `WP_DEBUG` to `TRUE`. This will hopefully provide us with more necessary information.

Comment: Thanks, Changed the theme, Error Still exists. Set `WP_DEBUG` to `TRUE`, Debug Log didn't display any errors, the Apache error was the same as above.